# Download Excel Spreadsheet Python

Tags: python, file

I am still pretty new to Python, so perhaps I am missing something obvious. I am trying to download a simple spreadsheet from Google Docs, save the file, and open it in Excel. When I did a test run with text files instead of excel files, it worked fine. However, using xls and xlsx, when excel opens the newly downloaded file, it says that the data is corrupted. How can I fix this?

```
import urllib2

print "Downloading..."
myfile = urllib2.urlopen("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AoJYUIVnE85odGZxVHkybGxYRXF1TFpuQXdqZlJwNXc&output=xls")
output = open('C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\downloaded.xlsx', 'w')
output.write(myfile.read())
output.close()
print "Done"

import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\EXCEL.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\downloaded.xlsx'])
```

Comment: Have you tried the `wb` flag when you open the file for writing?

Comment: you may want to try changing 'w' to 'wb'. the `b` flag means "write to this file in binary" rather than potentially ASCII or something..

Answer (score 2):

you would want to make it `wb` you can take a look at the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the file in plain-text, ascii mode. Excel documents are not plain text: under this assumption, you'll mishandle the content.

To use data as-is, with zero assumptions about its format, you use binary mode. Here:

```
output = open('C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\downloaded.xlsx', 'wb')
```

Notice the 'b' flag at the end.